# Prevent comma-separated list of numbers being interpreted as single large value

Tags: excel, vba

`33266500,332665100,332665200,332665300` was the original value, cell should look like this: `33266500,332665100,332665200,332665300` but what I see as the cell value in excel is `3.32665E+34`

So the question is I want to convert it into the original string. I have found format function on google and I used it like these

```
format(3.32665E+34,"standard")
```

giving it as `332,6650,033,266,510,000,000,000`

How to parse it or get back the orginal string? I belive format is the function in vba.

Comment: Where does the original value come from? Code? User? An imported text file? Somewhere else? It's probably important that we know that, as the correct value needs to be preserved as it's written to the cell to prevent Excel from making a wrong assumption and losing information.

Comment: yes and imported text file that number is generated by a machine the machine inserts it with , but excel converting it into exponential number!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Excel has a 15 digit precision limit. If the numbers are already shown like this when you access the file, there is no way to get the number back - you have already lost some digits. VBA code and formulas will not help you.

If this is not the case, you can add a single quote ' mark before the number to store it as text. This will ensure Excel does not try to treat it as a number and thus lose precision.

Comment: i both love this answer and hate that it's necessary

Answer (score 4):

If you want the value kept exactly, store the data as a string, not as a number. The data type you are using simply doesn't have the ability to do what you are asking it to do.

Answer (score 1):

The value needs to be entered into the cell as a string.  You need to make whatever it is that inserts the value preceed the value with a `'`.

Comment: That value is inserted by a machine I just get the file the machine is located somewhere miles away from me.

Comment: I need something to split these into the original string

Comment: So, what you are saying is you want the string inserted into 4 cells?

Comment: you will need to explain in detail how the data travels from the remote machine into your spreadsheet.  Currently whatever the process is it puts the data into a single cell, which excel interprets as a number (and because excel cells are limitied to 15 significant digits you get the value you describe).  There are many and varied ways data can be 'inserted' from remote sources, we need to know the details so we can suggest ways to modify it

Answer (score 1):

If you're starting with an Excel file that has already been created then you've already lost the information: Excel has tried to understand what it was given and its best guess has turned out to be wrong. All you can do (if you can't get the source data) is go back to the creator of the Excel file and tell them what's wrong.

If you're starting with, say, a text file that you're importing, then the news is much better:

If you're importing manually using the Text Import Wizard, then at "Step 3 of 3" you need to set "Column Data Format" for the problem field to "Text".

If you're using a macro, you'll need to specify a value for the `TextFileColumnDataTypes` property that does the same thing. The easiest way to get it right is to use the Macro Recorder.

If you want the four values in the string to be separate cells, then again, look at the Text Import Wizard settings: in Step 1 of 3 you need to set "Delimited" data type (usually the default) and in Step 2 make sure that "Comma" is checked.