# CSV value should be read as string, not time, into Excel

Tags: excel, csv

I have a PHP script that writes out data to a comma-separated (CSV) file.  One of the columns contains the coordinates of a star - e.g. 19:07:14.03.  When the CSV file is read into Excel, Excel assumes this is a time and converts the value to 07:14.0. Is there a way to embed some information in the CSV file that will tell Excel that the value should be read in as a string and not a time?  I have tried putting double quotes around the value but that doesn't work. Alternately, is there a setting in Excel that can force it not to auto-format the values?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525924/prevent-comma-separated-list-of-numbers-being-interpreted-as-single-large-value

Answer (score 3):

Rename file extension to `TXT`, then open it and go through import text wizard. On one of the steps you'll be able to define data type for columns - select `Text` for your time values. This should help.